# Install GNOME Onscreen Keyboard (GOK) in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: gnome, keyboard, software-center

According to [this link](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gok/) the GNOME On-Screen Keyboard should be available for v12.04, but when I click the link there for GOK in Software Center `apt://gok`, it tells me:

```
Not found
There isn’t a software package called “gok” in your current software sources.
```

So, what repository do I need to enable (and the command[s] to add it) in order to install GOK?

I want to try that on screen keyboard instead of the default "Onboard", because Onboard won't show me which key[s] is/are being pressed on the physical keyboard.

Thanks!

Comment: As per http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gok it seems like that package is in fact not available in precise...

Comment: So why does it say it **is** available on
https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gok/ 
?

Comment: I guess there's a bug on the way the webpage pick up packages, it seems like gok is still present as a virtual package, but no other package provides it, so it's just a ghost package, and apps.ubuntu.com seems to get the wrong idea.